# How to change labels from capital case to small case in the main grid of admin on rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

how do i make admin on rest main grid labels in regular case .as my application requires too many columns in the grid and all together it looks very bad and messy .i have created an en.json file and it's taking the value from there that is if the property is channelType and I have given in en.json as   "channelType": "Channel ", its showing "CHANNEL" itself in the grid but I want it to be in regular case such as "Channel", what should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `style` property on the `Datagrid` component. See the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#custom-grid-style)

```
const styles = {
    header: {
        textTransform: 'none',
    }
}

<Datagrid styles={styles}>
```

Comment: i added the above piece of code in custom datagrid code .Instead of converting the labels into regular case as my properties are defined all the headings are getting merged with the adjusent one.....

Comment: My mistake, as fzaninotto said on the duplicate issue in the AOR repository, that's not currently possible